# running mahout RecommenderJob on EMR

Tags: jar, mahout, amazon-emr, emr

I'm trying to run a RecommenderJob on amazon EMR. I have a jar called SmartJukebox.jar (not runnable) and it contains a class main.TrackRecommander (and that's it).

I created a job flow with the jar:

s3n://smartjukebox/SmartJukebox.jar

and args:

main.TrackRecommander --input s3n://smartjukebox/ratings.csv --output s3n://smartjukebox/output --usersFile s3n://smartjukebox/user.txt.

The class TrackRecommander uses the class RecommenderJob.

I run the job flow and i get this in the error log -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/hadoop/item/RecommenderJob
>       at main.TrackRecommander.main(TrackRecommander.java:136)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.hadoop.item.RecommenderJob
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>       ... 6 more

now i see that the JVM can't find RecommenderJob and i didn't put RecommenderJob in my jar. I thought EMR would have mahout jars built in, but i can't find anything about that.

what is the solution here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is exactly what you say: "I didn't put RecommenderJob in my jar." Unless you put those classes in your JAR, of course it can't be found. Why would EMR have this built in? Add the Mahout ".job" file classes to your JAR first.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but where do i find them? or maybe get a clue about what they are? it will be great if you could give a brief explanation. thanks for the help!

Comment: `mvn package` in the directory you unpacked the distribution. Then look in `target/` under the module you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a job jar which contains all the classes required by the code to run which includes the mahout classes too. 
Take a look at 
https://github.com/tdunning/MiA

Check how to create a job jar using maven assembly plugin in pom.xml and the job.xml in the src/main/resources directory.
IF you exclude the hadoop classes then you can run it on any hadoop instance.